# how to set error message of the independent form in the status bar of the mdi form in c#?

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, xml, linq

i have one independent form where i am checking read only access of an xml file ,
if the file is read only then i have to display message in the status bar of MDI form.
since i am using independent form to valid xml file, status bar of the MDI form is not displaying the error message.
now how to display message?

thanx in advance

Comment: mdi form in asp.net, did i miss a memo? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a reference of your MDI form to this new form and have the MDI form expose a method for setting messages.  Or you can expose an event on the independent form and have the MDI form register this to change its status bar when the form triggers a new message.

This assumes the independent form isn't a child form of the MDI container.